# rust mod statement's inconsistency

Tags: rust

Following the example in separating modules into different files from the following link:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-modules-and-use-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#separating-modules-into-different-files

I have created the following files under src directory:

```
├── main.rs
├── sound
│   └── instrument.rs
└── sound.rs
```

In `src/main.rs`:

```rust
mod sound;

fn main() {
  // Absolute path
  crate::sound::instrument::clarinet();

  // Relative path
  sound::instrument::clarinet();
}
```

In `src/sound.rs`:

```rust
pub mod instrument;
```

And in `src/sound/instrument.rs`:

```rust
pub fn clarinet() {
  println!("clarinet");
}
```

The example compiles and works as expected. Now my questions is: why in `main.rs`, it can "mod" the `sound.rs` from the same directory, while in `sound.rs`, it has to "mod" the `instrument.rs` from a sub-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a standard Rust bin project, `src/main.rs` is given a special position as the crate root. Other source files within `src/` are modules at the top level of the crate. Modules with multiple files can take one of two forms. The old way was like this:

```
├── main.rs
└── mod_name
    └── mod.rs
    └── submodule.rs
└── some_other_mod.rs
```

`mod.rs` was required (with that exact name), and would serve as the top level of the module. In this case you can see, I'm sure, that it wouldn't make sense for `src/mod_name/mod.rs` to refer to `some_other_mod` directly without prefixing it with `super::` or `crate::`.

The new method, which you are using, allows you to forgo `mod.rs` and just have `mod_name.rs` in the parent mod's directory, which serves the same purpose as `mod.rs`. This is convenient for when you start developing a library as a single file, and then when you later decide to add more files, you aren't required to rename and move the top level file.

In your case, `instrument.rs` needs to be in the `sound/` directory in order to be considered part of the `sound` module. If you placed it directly in `src/`, it would be considered a top level module in the crate.

Comment: Thanks. So in most cases, `module_name.rs` file and `module_name/` directory will coexist, is it correct?

Comment: If most modules have multiple files, then yes. I don't know if it's the case that most modules have multiple files though.